# Скрипт добавляет лишь одну (последнюю) строку в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Вот скрипт, добавляется лишь последняя строка из xml файла(всего их 4).
Подозреваю, что в коде чего-то не хватает, только понять чего именно не хватает опыта. Если добавить скрипт сразу после foreach, на экран выводится только первое значение, остальные игнорируются, и в базу добавляется уже не последнее а первое значение.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("worrrkers.xml") ;

     foreach($xml->children() as $worrrkers) { 
       echo '<span style="color:'.$worrrkers->color.'">'.$worrrkers- >name.'</span>' ."<hr>"; 


     }


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM testing WHERE name='$worrrkers->name'"; 
             $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
             $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

             if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                exit();
               } else {

               $sql = "INSERT INTO testing (name, color) VALUES ('$worrrkers->color', '$worrrkers->name');";
                mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                exit();

         }
```

Comment: код xml файла можно?

Comment: Он в моём предыдущем вопросе.

Comment: Ну, по коду и должно добавляться один раз, ибо у вас запрос вне цикла, а потом как выполнится еще и exit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("worrrkers.xml");

foreach ($xml->children() as $worrrkers)
{
    echo '<span style="color:'.$worrrkers->color.'">'.$worrrkers->name . '</span>' . "<hr>";

    $sql         = "SELECT * FROM testing WHERE name='$worrrkers->name'";
    $result      = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO testing (name, color) VALUES ('$worrrkers->color', '$worrrkers->name');";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
}
```